# almost how many words are there in Russian language?

Tags: словарь

When i saw a dictionary that contains almost three million words [Bigg English-Russian Dictionary](http://biggdictionary.com/?en#.V6ckoAerD-h.facebook)

Make me wonder to really know how many words are there in Russian language !

Is this the largest dictionary in the world ?

did you know any research on Russian words estimation ?

Comment: Russian has some rules on how to produce new words, so the number of possible words is vertually not limited.

Comment: To add to Anixx's statement, here is a list of Russian words that correspond to 3 English words "run, ran, running" http://img1.joyreactor.cc/pics/comment/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-863015.jpeg  The list is long due to various declensions. Additionally, there are words in the language that typically are not included in the dictionary, because their meaning can be deduced from similar words that are already in the dictionary.

Comment: I didn't know so far the Russian words have such flexible architecture from one root !

Comment: @Vitaly definitely the list omits a lot of words, for instance, all ones with prefixes раз-, под-, вы-, в-, от-, за-, про-, при-, о-. Only у- and с- prefixes included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, "three million entries" sounds a bit unbelievable.

Russian has ~200K words according to [Dal's dictionary](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0) (published in 1862, so *quite* obsolete); more modern dictionary, ["Словарь современного русского литературного языка"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0), is supposed to have ~150K entries, but it hasn't been fully published yet.
English [is estimated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language) to have ~170K words in current usage, and ~600K words including obsolete.

You can see the comparison of language sizes here: 
http://www.lingholic.com/how-many-words-do-i-need-to-know-the-955-rule-in-language-learning-part-2/
None of the compared languages has more than 500K words.

Comment: Thanks Roux your reply with the included links is definitive...

Comment: Dahl's dictionary is totally obsolete, even for then-modern language when it was composed. It includes a lot of dialectal and archaic words which were already very archaic by 1862.